# How do I specify an objects key with another variable in Handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

From an Ember template I'm trying to get an objects value using a variable for the key. How would I do this?

I've Tried the Following:

```
<table>
    {{#each record in model}}
    <tr>
        {{#each col in table.cols}}
            <td>{{record[col.field]}}</td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

Variables:

```
var table = {           
   cols: [{
        header: 'Date/Time',
        field: 'date'
    },{
        header: 'Address',
        field: 'address'
    },{
        header: 'Type',
        field: 'type'
    }]
};

var model = [{
    id: 1,
    date: '8/18/85',
    address: '123 abc st',
    type: 'Unique'
}, {
    id: 2,
    date: '9/8/95',
    address: '123 abc st',
    type:'Foreign'
}]
```

On build I'm getting the following error

`Parse error on line 25:
...}                {{record[col.field]}}
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'
Error: Parse error on line 25:
...}                {{record[col.field]}}
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a built in way, but you can create a template helper to do this for you.

Something like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('array-value', function(array, key, options) {
  return array[key];
});
```

And in your template you would call:

```
{{ array-value record col.field }}
```

Here is a [jsbin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/papagi/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Maybe a better name, with inspiration from clojure: `get-in`; it then becomes `{{ get-in record col.field}}`